# Adding an entirely new column to tbl_summary()

Tags: gtsummary

I built a table using tbl_summary() based on data collected from an original survey experiment in the US. The table outlines demographic information by treatment group. I want to add an additional column that lists demographic information based on the US census data (this is useful to reflect that my data is representative of the U.S. public). What is the best way to add this column of demographic data, which is *not* included in my survey data? I've looked at existing code online and this doesn't seem to relate to my situation. Should I build an entirely new dataset and merge the tables? [my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It13c.png)

Comment: Can you give an example of the information you would like to add in the new column? What is the structure?

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks. I simply want to add percentages from the U.S. Census in a new column on the right side of the existing table that correspond to the demographic variables I have listed on the far left side of the existing table - sex, age, ethnicity, education, income. This will allow reviewers to quickly check that my sample is representative of the U.S. population. The U.S. Census data is numeric.

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary ways to add columns to an existing gtsummary table.

1. Use the `add_stat()` function. Details here https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_stat.html
2. The second is to create a tibble of the results you want to add, and use the `modify_table_body()` function to add the table. After you merge in the additional column, you'll need to use `modify_header()` to add a column header for the new column (which will unhide the column as well). https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/modify_table_body.html

You can update your post with a reproducible example, and I can update the response with a code example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this tonight and be in touch.